# Understanding Base64 decoding

Tags: decryption

I have found following string in one of the CTF walkthrough. But I could not understand **1274*** string in the code. what is the significance of **1274*** in below code?

```
 1274* echo "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE....ErkJggg==" | base64 --decode > image.png
```

Comment: That bit doesn't appear to be meaningful. Maybe it's a copy-paste error.